# Ascending to humanity / descending from humanity

Tags: phrase-request

How can I say the following sentence in other words?

> "Ascending from humanity is difficult descending from humanity is so easy."

I mean we are close to the death of humanity. I could say we as human beings are no more social animals because we are becoming more and more selfish. We sometimes behave worse than animals. If this is continued, there will be end of humanity soon. As a conclusion, I wanted to say while it is easy to descend from our human essence and become inferior to animals and act like other people, it is really difficult to stay "human" and not get affected to a certain extent.

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements for how you want to say it?

Comment: Do you mean "ascending **from** humanity" or "humanity ascending"?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your intended meaning. Are you referring to moral behavior, evolutionary theory, or ... what?

Comment: I am referring to moral behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common phrase I can think of in English that corresponds to 'descending from humanity' is 'descending into savagery". It's used quite a bit when talking about the book [*Lord of the Flies*](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/flies/themes.html) which has some of the same themes as what I believe you're trying to express. The opposite of savagery is usually civilization.

I will have to think a bit longer about a good phrase for "ascending to humanity". I might say "being civilized is harder than descending into savagery", but I'm not completely happy with that phrasing.

Humanity in English has a connotation of being kind or compassionate. Being savage has a connotation of being like an animal. Civilization isn't always a positive thing though, while having humanity is positive in every context I can think of. In some writing, civilization has actually corrupted humanity by moving us further away from what is natural and being savage in the sense of "untamed" is not always a negative thing depending on the context and the point of view of the author.

Comment: You ascend both "from" and "to". You ascend from where you are to where you're going (e.g. "I ascended from the first floor to the fifth"). That said, to ascend from humanity would be to rise above humanity, which I think is the opposite of what the OP is trying to say.

Comment: @KenB You make a good point. Whether it's ascend from or ascend to is context dependent. It's not really relevant to the question, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't a question with a "right" answer. This is rhetoric, and it depends a lot on personal style and preference. Also, these types of ideas are difficult to put into words in general; native speakers often have just as tough of a time expressing thoughts like these, because they are difficult by nature.

To maybe set you on the right path, is this something you know how to express in your own first language? Maybe start by writing it out as clearly and simply as you can your most comfortable language first, then try to translate it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - maybe it should be a comment?  I don't understand why your advice is to "try to translate it". It seems to me like they've already tried to translate what they want to say into English by asking this question.

Comment: the answer is 'this probably isn't a question with a "right" answer'. Nothing more I can do there; I posted as an answer because this is in fact an answer to the question, even if it isn't the sort the OP would have liked. I didn't ask them to try to translate the same thing they've already tried to translate, I asked them to try and figure out exactly what they want to say in their native language first (which it appears they haven't done) and try to translate *that*.

Comment: What makes you think that what they've written isn't how they've translated their native language? You don't even know what their first language is. It's good discussion, which is why I haven't down voted, but it's not an answer.

Comment: Also, just because there isn't one 'right' answer to a question, doesn't mean that there aren't several good answers to a question.

Comment: What they've written is a long paragraph; I imagine they want a single punchy phrase. They did give a phrase, but it appears to me that the comments on the question have maybe changed what they want to say a bit, based on the paragraph that moved from a comment into the question in an edit.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. You shouldn't be answering questions that don't have enough information to write a good answer for. If you come across a question like that, it's best to leave a comment to ask for some clarification, and work out an answer after the author provides some clarification. Mia clarified the question, so now I think we can write a reasonable answer. The beauty of SE is that we can edit and improve every post and just flag the comments as obsolete as things evolve.

Comment: What I was implying is that I don't necessarily think this question is good for the format of this site, and trying to encourage the author to find a better way to state the question. They had already attempted a rephrasing, prompted by a comment, and that rephrasing indicated, IMO, that maybe they hadn't fully thought through the idea they want to express. Maybe a comment would have been better, maybe a vote to put the question on hold until it was rephrased, maybe, maybe. Apparently you think it can be answered as is; that's wonderful, I'm glad you were more capable than me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37304/discussion-between-colleenv-and-kenb).

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance.I appreciate your help.